# Replace a String with a text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, replace

What function can replace a string with another *Text*, means
get text from `.content`.
Like this `<div class="content">text</div>` and then place it here: `username : 'text'`

**Example #**

Html: `<div class="content">text</div>`

Place *text* to *username* from `.content`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#tweecool').tweecool({
 //settings
 username : 'I wan to Replace here', 
 limit : 5  
 });
});
```

*After replace it should be like this:*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#tweecool').tweecool({
 //settings
 username : 'text', 
 limit : 5  
 });
});
```

So how to replace a string with a text from specific `DIV` by jquery/JS.

Thanks!

Comment: Use `html()` jquery method

Comment: @JohnR  Thanks :), But How?

Comment: Now check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the text contents use .text() and use it in the setting like

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#tweecool').tweecool({
    //settings
    username: $('.content').text(),
    limit: 5
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://api.tweecool.com/js/tweecool.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">text</div>
<div id="tweecool"></div>
```

Comment: Wow, Thanks, but in my site `<div class="content">text</div>` is dynamically load when page load, so script is not able to get text from HTML source, on this case your script not working, so how to fix this?

Comment: @Aabira then you need to call it after updating the div content

Comment: Yes, i have tried this by : `setTimeout(function() {` but not working :(

Comment: @Aabira using timeout won't help... you need to do it after the content is loaded

Comment: Ok Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the text method

```
​$("#tweecool").text(function () {
    return $(this).text().replace("text", "hello world"); 
});​​​​​
```

Comment: Hi, i want to do like this: http://jsfiddle.net/9w4hw184/2/ #But in my site  `<div class="content">text</div>` is dynamically load when page load so script is not able to get text from HTML source, how to solve this?

Comment: I don't get your point? You tell me that in this feedle everything works, but it doesn't work in your website?

Comment: Yes, because `<div class="content">text</div>` is dynamically load when page load so script is not able to get text from HTML source.

Comment: Than defer the script and make him wait for the div to be loaded.

Comment: Yes, i have tried this by : `setTimeout(function() {` but not working :(

Answer (score 1):

For simple changing content. you could try like this.

```
$('div.content').html("username : 'text'");
```

But for your jQuery control like structure, you can customize it by using it's object like this.

```
var tObj = $("#tweecool").data("tweecool");
tObj.username = "text";
```

Comment: Thanks, It's not about replace HTML text, Trying to replace Example Jqury string.

Comment: @Aabira Like above code snippet,  create an object for your control. Through that object you can access all the properties of your jQuery control.

Comment: Hi, i want to do like this: http://jsfiddle.net/9w4hw184/2/ #But in my site  `<div class="content">text</div>` is dynamically load after page load so script is not able to get text from HTML source, how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Plz try This One:

StyleSheet:

```
<style type="text/css">
#overlay{
    display:none;
    background:red;
    width:200px;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px;
    border-radius:5px;
}
#overlay1{
    display:none;
    background:red;
    color:white;
    width:200px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px;
    border-radius:5px;
    }
    </style>
```

Jquery function:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"></script>




<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#overlay').fadeIn('fast').delay(1000).fadeOut('fast');
        });
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#overlay1').fadeOut('fast').delay(2000).fadeIn('fast');
        });
        </script
```

Body

```
<div id ="overlay">hi</div>
<div id ="overlay1">hello</div>
```